# Select numberplate from a table with a missing letter or number when the original numberplate can not be found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem:

A camera system is scanning numberplates to check if they can enter a parking.
Only numberplates in the table can enter.
Sometimes, the camera is missing a letter or number or is changing (misreading) one character.

For example I receive 'BE.TUVV129' instead of 'BE.1TUVV129' -> car cannot enter.

I created this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=395c12fe55d1d4870381b788fac08234 to count the number of letters/numbers found in the numberplate by selecting the highest count.
The problem here is that I sometimes end up with a wrong solution because the same characters can appear in another numberplate in a different order. Also numberplates can have from 2 to 10 characters.

Is there any solution to search for numberplates that matches the original characters in the same order with a maximum of 1 error in the string?
What I need to do is:
First select the numberplate from the camera, and second, only when not found, search for a numberplate that is like the original one with a 'mistake'...  This must be in one select statement.

```
+--------------+
| Numberplate  |  
+--------------+
|BE.1GGTT531   |
|BE.364BDRM    |
|BE.1TUVV129   |
|BE.2BCMV569   |
|BE.1FIP479    |
|BE.XDB6501    |
|BE.1XJJ6E34   |
|BE.80T8XZH    |
|BE.2AQHL897   |
|BE.2BFL4G22   |
|BE.2BFL4H11   |
|BE.1UTEB280   |
|BE.1RJHH864   |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Search for external user-defined function which calculates "Levenshtein distance", "Damerau–Levenshtein distance" or some similar metrics amnd use it.

Comment: Hi that's an interesting point, however I can not use functions in this case. the call must be one SQL select statement and must return one record.

Comment: *I can not use functions in this case* Why? of course you can implement this algorithm in your query without the function - but this query will be extremely complex. If you cannot use user-defined function from external module then create stored user-defined function and use it. PS. It is bad practice to perform the operation with hand-made code when std. framework/library/function/another implementation can be applied.

Comment: because the call is made from the camera system to a mysql cloud database. this is not a PC but a PLC system with a simple integrated sql functionallity.  The camera can ony do a select statement and one record must return.  This record is used and updated for the entered car.   I'll try to create a function in the cloud and see if this can be used.

Comment: check this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4ca5035d1157b79bf715b54d894b6711

Comment: *The camera can ony do a select statement and one record must return.* The user-defined function is the functoin which is registered and used in the query on MySQL side. Your camera will send the SELECT query in which this function is used as common build-in function. About the fiddle: see [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ddfb170fc484d133fd667f6baf57399d). If observed query execution time is safe for you then use this solution.

Comment: *the camera is missing a letter or number or is changing (misreading) one character* If so then you need in 2 separate functions. 1st one with "change" as the only valid edition, and another with "insert" as the only valid edition.

Comment: Hi @Akina I don't understand the previous message.  (with change and insert function) When i test my dbfiddle it is working fine with the one function.  When one character is missing or misread the result = 1,  so i know it's the correct numberplate.  I suppose that all records with a result < 2 are valid since the question is: maximum one error in the numberplate

Comment: Levenschtein and another similar algos operates with some tiny list of allowed actions/editions. These can be: (1) insert a letter (2) remove a letter (3) replace a letter, (4) etc... and the distance calculated by the algo is min. amount of actions which converts one string to another. So you must either create universal function with definite list of allowed actions or separate functions with only one action allowed. If you tell that there is only 2 possible misrecognizings then you may use either one function with 2 allowed actions (no. 1 and 3) or 2 separate functions.